# Markup Validation, Errors found

Tags: php, html, wordpress, validation, w3c-validation

I've tried recently to validate a web page and every time I run the validator it outputs the same errors, although the structure of the page seems legit.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
...
```

It should be something wrong with the source but I can't figure it out..
[link to markup validation results](https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdemo.amiron.eu%2Fequilibrium%2F&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&st=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3%20http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices)

Comment: validation + wordpress is a headache. I would ignore such errors as it is very hard to fix without going deep into theme core files.

Comment: @felix91 I get these errors even on blank html pages.

Comment: I too, I just ignore them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on looking at the actual errors the document contains, a few recommendations:

#### Use the current W3C HTML Checker at https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Check your document with https://validator.w3.org/nu/ not https://validator.w3.org/.

https://validator.w3.org/ is written in Perl and uses SGML and DTDs to perform validation and so is very limited in the kinds of checks it can do (e.g., it can’t do precise datatype/microsyntax checking of attribute values). And if your doc uses a modern doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html>`, the “HTML5” doctype declaration), it just hands the doc off to https://validator.w3.org/nu/ for checking anyway.

https://validator.w3.org/nu/ checks your document against [the current HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/) (*aka* HTML5), and includes many types of checks which https://validator.w3.org/ cannot do.

Checking https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http://demo.amiron.eu/equilibrium/ brings up two points:

#### Always start your documents with `<!DOCTYPE html>`

The document at http://demo.amiron.eu/equilibrium/ currently doesn’t have any [document type declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_declaration#HTML5_DTD-less_DOCTYPE) at all. That’s an outright error, because the lack of a doctype can cause unexpected behavior in browsers. And if you use any doctype other than `<!DOCTYPE html>` it is also easier to get part of the doctype wrong in a way that cause unexpected behavior in browsers.

#### Always include `<meta charset="utf-8">` in your documents

The character encoding for http://demo.amiron.eu/equilibrium/ is not declared in the HTTP headers that the document is served with nor in the document itself. Documents on the Web should be encoded in UTF-8 and to be certain their encoding is always made clear to browsers and other tools, documents should always include a `<meta charset="utf-8">` element.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt answer. Excuse my inexperience, but I still don't understand why the imported page source used for validation looks like this? `<html><head><style>.loader-walk{width: 100px; height: 40px; ...` It's not what my page source looks like.

Comment: There’s not any special “imported page source used for validation”. The validator sees the same source that browser see; that is, whatever your Web server is sending. To see what your Web server is sending, do **View source** in a browser (or open view-source:http://demo.amiron.eu/equilibrium/), or if you have the `curl` or `wget` tools installed, do `curl -o OUT.html http://demo.amiron.eu/equilibrium/` or `wget -O OUT.html http://demo.amiron.eu/equilibrium/` and then open the `OUT.html` file and take a look at it. What I see is, the entire document is on one line, with no doctype.

Comment: So if what you see from **View source** (or those other ways described above of seeing what your server is sending) is different from the source you’ve created an uploaded to the host your Web server runs on, then that means something (I guess Wordpress) is altering your source on the server side before sending it.